# How can I launch a folder whose name contains a comma, using ProcessStartInfo in C#?

Tags: c#, explorer, processstartinfo

I have an app that queries a database for the location of a nested folder used for a task, and opens this folder (using the `ProcessStartInfo` class to launch `explorer.exe` and pass in the folder name as an argument).

This works fine except for a number of folders that contain commas (and unfortunately there are a load of them!)

Say, for a folder called `C:\this,folder\`, it tries to launch "folder". How can I get it to treat the comma as verbatim?

Sample code:

```
public void LaunchExplorer() {
        ProcessStartInfo explorer = new ProcessStartInfo();             

        string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR");
        System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = windir + @"\explorer.exe ";
        prc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"c:\this,folder";
        prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        try                                       
        {                
            prc.Start();
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("cannot open folder " + prc.StartInfo.Arguments);
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe enclose in quotes (`"c:\this,folder"`)?

Comment: explorer warns you that the folder "folder" does not exist - it is treating the comma as a leading comma, i.e. trying to open "folder" instead of "c:\this,folder"

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried enclosing the folder name in quotes, like this?

```
prc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"c:\\this,folder\"";
```

Comment: now all I need to do is put in the fields populated by the database query, i.e.:  prc.StartInfo.Arguments = pathPrefix + @"\" + workingPath;

Answer (score 0):

```
prc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"c:\\this,folder\"";
```

will do the trick